# Changing IP range that holds the Primary Domain Controller

Tags: windows, ip, domain, controller

My domain includes a few /24 ranges over an MPLS and we've recently acquired a business which uses the same /24 range as my Primary domain controller (172.17.0.0/24).
Because of this clash, I have 2 options.

1. Change the range of the acquired business
2. Change the range that my Primary Domain controller sits on.

Management is leaning towards #2, because the new business has a more complex mix of servers (but all within their own 172.17.0.0/24 range).

However, I have some concerns about #2 as the PDC is in it, which could potentially complicate matters quite a bit.

My initial thoughts are to add a secondary domain controller with the same IP as the PDC on the acquired business, so at least some legacy devices with hard coded DNS won't be up shit creek if the ip range update doesn't go as planned.

Would like some advise on how I should proceed.
If anyone has been in a similar situation and has a guide/playbook of sorts, would be much appreciated!

Comment: No, changing an IP address of a DC is typically not something you want to do. Add another DC with a different IP address in the new range.

Comment: Thank you Greg, Its worse than that. Its changing the entire IP range that the DC is on. So not only will the DC change IP, the old range will cease to exist.